# How to capture flat file timestamps in SSMS

Tags: sql-server

This is my first attempt to ask a question on this forum. I'm currently running a local instance of SQL2008 R2 on my machine. I have Googled many different ways to get this exact question answered but had no luck so far.

Simply put, I want to know how to capture a Windows flat file (foobar.txt) timestamp using t-sql code. I am totally new to MS SQL, and so far all I have run across is an undocumented sp called "xp_DirTree" which comes close but doesn't give me what I need. Is there a simple function that I'm overlooking here?

Comment: What's your use case? Is this a file you're importing into the database? Or are you trying to build a file listing w/ names & timestamps on a table from the filesystem?

Comment: Both. As part of my job I have to import various versions of the same file. It would be HUGELY useful to capture the timestamp of each version I import.

Comment: Look into SSIS. It's built for handling (among other things) file imports & data transformations/loads, and as part of that you'll be able to capture the timestamp of the file you're importing.

Comment: Sad to say I tried SSIS a few months back with no luck. I spent a morning attempting to set up an import package with no clue what I was doing. Predictably, it didn't go well. Our office has already created a working file import script, but I am hoping to augment it with the file's timestamp. Should be do-able, but...

Comment: I agree.. use ETL not SQL for this.  SSIS is a good way to go.  Here are tutorials on how to make it work for you:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure how you could expect success with SSIS when attempting to use it with no knowledge of how it's meant to be used. It really is the best tool for this task. Getting the basics down for doing a simple import should not take long.

Comment: Wasn't given any choice in the matter. Thanks for your help, I'll look at the tutorials in my spare time at home. At least I saved what I was working on at the time, maybe I can salvage some of it. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In SSIS there is a Logging feature. Create a new connection for Logging and link to the SQL Server database. You can select what features should be stored in the new table. The new table created will be named as "sysssislog" inside System Tables.